# Why should I include a client_id in an OAUTHv2 password grant request?

Tags: authentication, passwords, oauth

Like little red riding hood, you don't know who is knocking on the door... Why even bother accepting a client_id in case of a API <-> Javascript-website or API <-> Android App password grant authentication flow?

Answer (score 1):

From [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-22) (emphasis mine):

> A client **MAY** use the "client_id" request parameter to identify itself
> when sending requests to the token endpoint.  In the
> "authorization_code" "grant_type" request to the token endpoint, an
> unauthenticated client MUST send its "client_id" to prevent itself
> from inadvertently accepting a code intended for a client with a
> different "client_id".  This protects the client from substitution of
> the authentication code.  **(It provides no additional security for the
> protected resource.)**